# YUI Compression VB vs C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, yui

I am converting a minification function from visual basic:

```
example = Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(someString, False, True, True, True, -1, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

to c#. However, the compress method in c# only takes a string argument and has no overload methods. Is the below code in c# equivalent to the original VB code above?

```
var compressor = new Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor();
example = compressor.Compress(someString);
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't use the same static method `Compress` as before, without newing an object in C#? It should be the same assembly under the covers.

Comment: @Rup I get an object reference error if I use the same static method as I did in VB

Comment: @Rup: There doesn't appear to be a static `Compress` function in the library at all, which is written in C#. I'm not sure how the VB version works either (I'm assuming it doesn't, or was part of an older version of the library). The current code for `JavaScriptCompressor`: http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Code/Yahoo.Yui.Compressor/JavaScriptCompressor.cs

Comment: @Cory: Yes, there is - it's in the Compressor base class.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: But it's not static and only takes a single `string` parameter.

Comment: I think suhMAN needs to check exactly what was being called in VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in C#, as far as I can tell from [the source](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), would require you to set the respective properties in the `JavaScriptCompressor` instance yourself instead of passing them to the (seemingly non-existent) `static Compress` method. For example:

```
var compressor = new Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor
{
    Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8,
    DisableOptimizations = false,
    ObfuscateJavascript = true,
    PreserveAllSemicolons = true,
    IgnoreEval = true,
    ThreadCulture = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
};

var example = compressor.Compress(someString);
```

The Boolean properties may not be in the same order as they were previously, so I just guessed. There's a `JavaScriptCompressorConfig` class in the library with these properties but I couldn't find how it would get passed to the compressor.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the static `Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Compress` method in VB.NET and instanciating a `Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor` class in C#.

You can call `Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.Compress` in C# to reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: Except that method doesn't exist in the current version of the library... http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Code/Yahoo.Yui.Compressor/JavaScriptCompressor.cs